# Excel How to hyperlink to filtered data

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have more than 2 sheets in an excel file, where one sheet (A) has the data that I want to filter. In other sheets, I want to have a hyperlink each that when clicked, will link to sheet A which is displaying the filtered data according to that sheet.

for example, in Sheet A, I have the following data

```
A - apple
B - book
C - cat
A - angel
B - bread
```

In another sheet, i have a hyperlink to filtered data "A" so when it is clicked, sheet A will display:

```
A - apple
A - angel
```

In another sheet, it will show filtered data in sheet A when clicked on the hyperlink:

```
B - book
B - bread
```

I heard about VBA but I have no idea on it. Is there another simpler way to do this without using VBA? If not, can you give me a guideline on the VBA for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed do this using VBA. Your best bet as a VBA beginner is to:

1. [Use the record macro functionality](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/record-and-use-excel-macros-HA001054837.aspx), and then
2. [Create a button](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-HP010236676.aspx) (I don't think you can create a hyperlink to a macro) which executes the desired macro

I did this for your first example (5 lines of data, I added a header) and the resulting VBA code was as follows:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$6").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="A"
```